# Javascript - download jasper file via browser

Tags: javascript, download

I'm implementing a download via button click that works on text files but it doesn't on other types of files.

For example, this works

```
var params = {};

if(this.ARow.Kind=='Data'){
params.rowid=this.ARow.rowid;
params.SESSION_ID=this.ARow.SESSION_ID+'';
params.NAME = this.ARow.NAME+'';
params.JRXML = this.ARow.JASPER_REPORT_JRXML+'';
params.TYPE = 'JRXML';
}

var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(atob(params.JRXML)));
    element.setAttribute('download', params.NAME.concat('.jrxml'));

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
```

I'm download .jrxml which is esentially, a text file and I can open it in Jaspersoft studio and it works.

Now, when I try to do the same for jasper files. They look like this

[image]

Via same way

```
var params = {};

if(this.ARow.Kind=='Data'){
params.rowid=this.ARow.rowid;
params.SESSION_ID=this.ARow.SESSION_ID+'';
params.NAME = this.ARow.NAME+'';
params.JASPER = this.ARow.JASPER_REPORT+'';
params.TYPE = 'JASPER';
}

var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(atob(params.JASPER)));
    element.setAttribute('download', params.NAME.concat('.jasper'));

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
```

It doesn't work since I'm not downloading a text file.

when I upload it to fileChecker it says

File Type: data
MIME Type: application/octet-stream;

How should I modify this part of code so that I can download it and that it is a valid .jasper file that can be opened through JasperSoft Studio.

Comment: *"MIME Type: application/octet-stream"* - Then why is the code explicitly indicating `data:text/plain`?  Did you just forget to change that?

Comment: I tried that, It would download the file, but I'd still get error when trying to open it in JasperSoft Studio, maybe there's different charset for that?